# ModBus RTU with PCON c#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, modbus

I am trying to simulate my pc as the master slave for an IAI servo, but I cant seem to send the command Correctly. Can anyone show me a function to send a jog, move, or even on/off command in C# ModBus RTU. An example query provided by the manual is  01 10 9900 0009 0000 000A 0000 2710 001E 0000 0008 F3A0 with a response of 01 10 9900 0009 2E93

There aren't a lot of resources online for my specific example and could use help understanding what I'm doing. Thanks in advance any help or knowledge is appreciated.

Comment: There are a few free Modbus RTU related tools that you can find on Github to help read and write data. The manual for the servo is pretty specific in command structure. See manual starting on pg 188. of this url https://www.intelligentactuator.com/pdf/controller-manuals/MODBUS(ME0162-10B).pdf